# "is" or "was" or at the end of the sentence

Tags: grammar, tense

I was talking to my friend (let's name them X).

X: There was some other person too.
Me: who is the "other person"?
X: Well, if I remember I would have already told who that person is

Now, my question is, what is correct:

- "Well, if I remember, I would have already told who that person is." or
- "Well, if I remember, I would have already told who that person was."?

Comment: "told" in this context requires an indirect object, ie "I would already have told *you/them/whoever* who that person is."

Comment: @Esther yeah... looks like X forgot to mention it. In this case, the indirect object is "you".

Comment: And "if I remember" suggests present or future action while "would have already" suggests past action, so there is an inconsistency there.

Comment: Also, it should be _if I remembered I would have told you._  X could say _If I remember (if I think of it in the future) I will tell you._

Comment: @KateBunting How about "*If I knew*..."?

Comment: _If I knew, I would have already told you who it was._

Answer (score 1):

In your example, it should be '*was*', least of all because person X said in the first line "there *was* some other person", and you should keep consistency in tense.

It's evident that the dialogue is about some event in the past.